# Issue in performing a segue in unwind segue method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I created an `unwind segue` and its working perfectly but from this `unwind segue method` I am trying to perform another `segue` but its not working. What can possibly wrong.

Comment: little code would be more helpful

Comment: I suspect that it's an animation related issue as happens many times when combining segues, but its impossible to answer without code

Comment: Why are you trying to unwind + segue in the same code? You're trying to have a controller remove itself but add another VC before it's dealloced. Your flow is incorrect - you shouldn't be doing this. It sounds like you're trying to do a tabbar functionality. It's probably not working because you're doing an unwind + a segue animation simultaneously.

Comment: I have a condition in unwind segue if it happens perform another segue. This kind of condition mostly happen in messengers kind of app may you have also experienced this, when selecting a contact an app directly show a chat view and when navigate from chat view we are on other tab.

Comment: @ LyricalPanda please can you write this as an answer as I can vote it.